# auth0lock's future functions not firing

Tags: angular, dart, auth0

I'm writing an angular2 application with auth0 authentication using dart.

so I inject the following class to the main app angular2 component:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:auth0_lock/auth0_lock.dart';
import 'app.config.dart';

@Injectable()
class Auth {
Auth0Lock lock;

Auth() {
    this.lock = new Auth0Lock(configObj.auth0.apiKey, configObj.auth0.domain);
}
updateProfileName(data) {
  var profile = data['profile'] != null ? data['profile'] : data;
  print(profile['name']);
}

authenticated() {
  return false;
}

login() {
  print("####LOGiN####");
    this.lock.show(options: {
      "callbackURL": configObj.auth0.callbackUrl
    },popupMode: true).then(this.updateProfileName).catchError(this.handleError).whenComplete(loginCompleted);
}

handleError(e) {
  print(e);
}

loginCompleted() {
  print("completed");
}
}
```

in my angular2 view I call `login()` which opens the login popup. after a successful or failure login none of the future functions are being called (`updateProfileName()`,`handleError()` and `loginCompleted()`).

this is my app component's code:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
import 'welcome_component.dart';
import 'auth_service.dart';


@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/www/my-app.html',
  providers: const [Auth]
)
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, name: 'welcome')
])
 class AppComponent {
  Auth auth;
  AppComponent(Auth auth) {
    this.auth=auth;
  }
}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What should fire and when?

Comment: the expected behaviour is that updateProfileName(),handleError() or loginCompleted() will be fired upon completion of the login process

Comment: Hard to tell. This doesn't depend on the code you shared but on `Auth0Lock.show()` returns.

Comment: The dart implementation of auth0lock is pretty old. Maybe it doesn't work well with the api auth0 provides today

Comment: One year isn't too old. Have you tried without Angular?

Comment: No. I'll try later and let ya  know. Thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried without angular, actually i tried the provided example. and it doesn't work with auth0 10, only with version 7.5

Comment: Then a bug report in the auth0lock package might be worth a try.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, that's my bug report :) i'll add another one for this issue

Comment: I meant to report it at https://github.com/andresaraujo/auth0_lock.dart/issues. Maybe just post a link to this SO question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: did that. thanks

Comment: https://github.com/andresaraujo/auth0_lock.dart/issues/2

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I'm trying to expose auth0 api myself using js.dart and having problem. if possible, please take a look. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949551/using-js-dart-to-expose-auth0-api

Comment: I had a look already but it seems it's too long ago already that I used dart-js-interop. Perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - thanks :)