# using js.dart to expose auth0 API

Tags: dart, auth0

I'm writing an Dart Angular2 application but it's irrelevant to the problem at hand.

I'm trying to use Auth0Lock with dart by exposing it's API using 1https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js.

I'm using Dartium to debug the application.

so I'm exposing the Auth0Lock API using the following auth0lock.dart file:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
class Auth0Lock {
 external factory Auth0Lock(String token, String domain, Object options);
  external on(String event, Function func);
  external show();
}
```

I exposed only the basic stuff I need.

then I created an Angular2 service in a file named `auth0_service.dart` that has the following code:

import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'auth0lock.dart';
import 'app.config.dart';

```
@Injectable()
class Auth {
Auth0Lock lock;

Auth() {
    this.lock = new Auth0Lock(configObj.auth0.apiKey, configObj.auth0.domain,{});
}
updateProfileName(data) {
  var profile = data['profile'] != null ? data['profile'] : data;
  print(profile['name']);
}

authenticated() {
  return false;
}

login() {
    this.lock.show().then(this.updateProfileName);
}


}
```

I'll also show my `index.html` where I load auth0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="www/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.0.0/lock.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/web/main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script defer src="/packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run my application I get the ollowing error:

```
EXCEPTION: No static method 'Auth0Lock.' declared in class 'Auth0Lock'.
```

so Auth0Lock is not a static method, it's a constructor for the class. so I must used the JS api wrong somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i need to prepend to the `auth0lock.dart` the following:

```
@JS()
library test;
```

actually I can rename `test` to anything I want... iI just need to add the js tag and library with a name. that solved it.